# Overriding Maven plugin goal definition for a given execution id

Tags: plugins, configuration, maven

It doesn't seem to possible to override a plugin execution's goal definition.

Let say I have a parent config of Jetty, that defines a

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
```

now I want locally for a specific project the goal run-exploded

If I try to override the parent definition in local project with

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
```

then I have the effective pom becomes

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                            <goal>run-exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
```

I'm surprised, as I have always thought it would override.

Is this a new behavior in Maven3 ?

Is there anyway to get an overriding behavior instead of current one?

Comment: Official doc says "Executions of the same id from different POMs are merged", see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#using-the-executions-tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way I found is to disable inherited configuration and creating a new one:

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well this is inheritance working the way as designed. You should consider removing your jetty config from the parent pom and put it in a profile or your try the `<inherited>` element with value false and see if this works for you.

Comment: good to know about inherited but has a weird behavior with jetty plugin and besides, that's not what I want, I need inheritance.

Comment: if you interpret the question globally, it's much rather about plugin override in the children poms than about running Jetty itself.