# Changing when maven runs integration tests

Tags: maven, integration-testing, lifecycle, maven-surefire-plugin

We have unit tests (mockito) and integration tests (in-memory database)
We'd like maven to *not* run the integration tests as part of 'mvn install'.
Basically I think this means reconfiguring the lifecyle so that integration-test
comes between install and deploy.  Is this possible?

The reason for this would be that the integration tests are somewhat time consuming
and so we don't want them to run every time a developer does an install.  But we would
like them to be run before the project can be released, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs for the plugin you use for running integration tests (possibly Failsafe) - simply exclude the tests, or set the plugin execution to false.

Comment: Right now our unit and integration tests are both run by surefire.  If developers could, for example exclude **IntegrationTest.java in their settings.xml (as opposed to the pom) that might be a solution.

Comment: @wytten You should rename them to ...IT.java, and start using failsafe instead IMHO

Comment: Thanks that does appear to be the best practice, but I still don't know how to defer their running until later in the cycle.

Comment: Later in the cycle? Or switching them off altogether? If you simply want them to run a different phase, do the following: move your ITs to a separate source folder (standard is src/it/java), and set up the Failsafe plugin in your pom. Your ITs will then run in the integration-test phase of the maven build process. This will still run when you do maven install though. If you simply want to only run them when you're ready, I'd suggest moving to using Failsafe (as above), then creating a new maven profile in your pom where Failsafe is switched on

Comment: We have recently discovered junit categories and so can achieve this without needing to use failsafe.  Here is a good intro http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0

Answer (score 1):

Does integration-tests just execute a single plugin (like surefire)? If so, it is probably easier to just [bind the plugin execution to a different phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        ...
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>execution1</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <configuration>
            ...
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea...Currently both unit and integration tests are being run by surefire, but if we moved the integration tests to failsafe, and bound failsafe execution to deploy phase, that might work.

Comment: Bind the failsafe plugin to the integration-test phase instead of the deploy phase.

Comment: You should also be able to override the surefire configuration and control those executions independently a la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760088/overriding-maven-plugin-goal-definition-for-a-given-execution-id. But using a different plugin like failsafe is another way to do almost the same thing.

Comment: This does not appear to work; I tried binding failsafe plugin execution to deploy phase, and it did not run the integration test before the deploy.

Comment: Did you try the install phase?